# Unity Resources.Load not working on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

This code below works just fine in the editor / windows but does not work in Android build. Sprite change does not occur. Any reasons why?

```
spr = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/Projectile");
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spr;
```

Comment: Anything in device log? using logcat http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/571021/view.html

Comment: Well looks like no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I solved it. It has nothing to do with the Resources.Load function. Turns out the buttons were calling an inactive instance instead of the right instance of the object that contains the sprite change function.

Comment: nice, and adding Debug.Log() message before/after resources load would had helped, since it would show in that log (if it gets run)